# What is the easiest way to rename the file you're currently editing in Vim?

Tags: vim

What would be the most practical way to rename the file you're currently editing in Vim without messing up your current *splits* configuration?

Generally, one would need to ... save the file under a different name, delete the original one, and re-open the new one without making a mess of the current layout.

Anyone have any idea how to do that in one command (function) or less?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`:saveas newname` will save the buffer with the new name, make that name the current buffer, and set the alternate buffer to the old file.

`:call delete(expand('#'))` will then delete the file associated with the alternate buffer.

You can easily turn that into a command with something like

```
:command! -bang -complete=file -nargs=+ Rename saveas<bang> <args> | call delete(expand('#'))`
```

---

The [user manual](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/usr_toc.txt.html) provides a thorough description of how to create [user commands](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/usr_40.txt.html#40.2).  Here's an explanation of the elements I'm using above.

- `-bang` allows the command to called as either `Rename` or `Rename!` and `<bang>` in the constructed command is replaced by either an empty string or `!`, depending on how it is called.  This is used to support the same functionality in the `:saveas` command.
- `-complete=file` will let you tab-complete the path that will be used for the new file, similar to `:e` and `:saveas` do.
- `-nargs=+` specifies that `:Rename` requires at least one argument (the filename), but can take more.  `<args>` is replaced with whatever arguments are given to `:Rename`.  This allows you to specify the extra arguments that `:saveas` accepts, so you could do something like `:Rename ++enc=latin1 newfile` to rename the file to newfile and change the encoding to latin1.

Comment: This is a good answer in that it does not mess with your window layout  at all.

Comment: Would it be too much to ask, if you could just explain what every part before the | does? I've a little hard time figuring it out from the help alone ... apart from that, it works perfectly!

Answer (score 3):

Tim Pope has a plugin that has a function `:Rename` that does this: [vim-eunuch](https://github.com/tpope/vim-eunuch).

You can also do the following sequence of steps:

```
:saveas newfile
:bw <buffer_for_the_old_file>
:!rm old_file
```

of course this is not as nice as renaming the file in the shell.

Comment: This looks like the cleanest approach. Voted it up.

Answer (score 2):

Call up the explorer with `:Explorer` or just `:E`, select your file, and then press `r` to rename.

Comment: note that this requires the netrw plugin (present in a vast majority of not minimalistic runtimes)

Answer (score 0):

Use `:Move` provided by [eunuch](https://github.com/tpope/vim-eunuch).

eunuch also provides other useful file operations, like `:Remove`, sudoedit.